# C++ - Last value in array gets duplicated in map

Tags: c++, xcode, stl, maps

I'm trying to create a dictionary of words from a sentence using a map and an array of strings. My problem is every time I loop through to add values to the map from my array the last item always gets duplicated as a key. This is all on xCode by the way.

```
int main(){
    char input[50];
    int i = 0,
    arr_size = 0;

    string s[20];

    cout << "Please input a phrase: ";
    cin.getline(input, 50);

    while(i < sizeof(input) - 1)
    {
        input[i] = tolower(input[i]);
        if(isspace(input[i]) || ispunct(input[i]) )
            arr_size++;
        else
            s[arr_size].operator+=(input[i]);
        i++;
    }


    map<string, int> dictionary;

    for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        if(dictionary.map::find(s[i]) == dictionary.end())
            dictionary.insert(make_pair(s[i], 1));
        else
            dictionary.at(s[i])++;
    }

  typedef map<string, int>::const_iterator MapIt;
      for (MapIt iter = dictionary.begin(); iter != dictionary.end(); iter++)
      {
           cout <<  iter->first << " : " << iter->second << endl ;

       }
}
```

With my output looking something like this:

```
Please input a phrase: thE Blue Black BluE Cat Cat BLacK hat zap zap
black : 2
blue : 2
cat : 2
hat : 1
the : 1
zap : 1
zap : 1
```

Comment: Post the code that prints the dictionary. See this: [MCVE].

Comment: The code above does not reproduce the issue. Please post the code that generates the error. When you have it fixed (not before it is fixed) you should get your code reviewed [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Note broken code is not reviewed.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The two "zap"'s are not the same. Probably the last one contains a newline character, '\n'. More generally, you need to learn how to index loops properly.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out while I was looping through

```
while(i < sizeof(input) - 1)
{
    input[i] = tolower(input[i]);
    if(isspace(input[i]) || ispunct(input[i]) )
        arr_size++;
    else
        s[arr_size].operator+=(input[i]);
    i++;
}
```

I didn't check for any other characters besides punctuation and space so it was reading in everything else.

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(input) - 1; i++)
    {

        if(isspace(input[i]) || ispunct(input[i]))
            arr_size++;
        else if (isalpha(input[i])){
            input[i] = tolower(input[i]);
            s[arr_size].operator+=(input[i]);
        }
    }
```

This code worked out better and is indexed a little better.

Comment: So what @Jive said! Look up `operator>>` to see that it does when applied to a stream and a string.

Comment: After you call `getline()` the number of characters read is found by calling `gcount()` on the stream. This value should be used instead of `sizeof(input)` which is the size of the buffer (not the size of the input).